# Indexing an array of unknown length in Python (Numpy, PyTorch)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array of shape `[m, 2, m, 2, ...]`. By this, I mean that it has dimensions of size `m` and `2` that repeat a number of times `L`. I would like a solution of the following that works for any given `L`.

Example:

- For `L=1` the array would be of shape `[m, 2]`
- For `L=2` the array would be of shape `[m, 2, m, 2]`
- For `L=3` the array would be of shape `[m, 2, m, 2, m, 2]`
- And so on...

I would like to index this array, in the dims of size `m`, with another array `indices` of shape `[L, N]` such as to eventually obtain an array of size `[N, 2, 2, ...]`.

For a given `L` (e.g. `L=3`), I would do the indexing as follows,

```
array[indices[0], :, indices[1], :, indices[2], :]
```

resulting in an array of shape `[N, 2, 2, 2]`.

Is there a smart way to do the indexing for generic `L`?

(Hope to have made the question clear!)

Edit 1:

To give idea of behavior, an ugly solution:

```
def indexing(array, indices):

    L = indices.shape[0]
    if L == 1:
        array = array[indices[0]]
    elif L == 2:
        array = array[indices[0], :, indices[1], :]
    elif L == 3:
        array = array[indices[0], :, indices[1], :, indices[2], :]
    elif L == 4:
        array = array[indices[0], :, indices[1], :, indices[2], :, indices[3], :]
    # etc...
    
    return array
```

And a use example:

```
import torch

m = 5
N = 4
L = 3
array = torch.randn(m, 2, m, 2, m, 2)
indices = torch.randint(m, size=(L, N))

indexing(array, indices).shape # torch.Size([4, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: How do you know the shape and content of *indices* if you don't know *L*?

Comment: I probably phrased it in a misleading way. I would like to write a function of L that does that. When the function is called, L is specified. I just mean that the solution should work for all L.

Comment: I provided a solution with `if`s that does the job for small L and a test example.

Comment: `p = torch.arange(0, array.ndim, 2); array.permute(*p,*p+1)[tuple(indices)]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len()`! Pretty simple usage:

```
length = len(array)
for i in range(0, length):
    # do something
```

You can also access the last item of the array whatever its length is by indexing `-1`, like so:

```
array = [1, 1, 5, 2, 4, ..., 99]
print(array[-1]) # 99
```